# Remove index.html from url with trailing slash , web-server nginx

Tags: nginx, url, redirect, http-status-code-301, slash

Please,help to configure 301 redirect in nginx config for removing index.html from url and trailing slash.
For example:

```
https://example.com/page1/page2/index.html > https://example.com/page1/page2
```

```
https://example.com/page1/page2/index.html/ > https://example.com/page1/page2
```

```
https://example.com/page1/index.html > https://example.com/page1
```

```
https://example.com/index.html > https://example.com or https://example.com/
```

Comment: Please check the try_files and rewrite directives. with a combination of them both, you can easily do what you are asking for. In fact, this is widely documented and shouldn't be a problem anyone that tries and research a minimum would face. Maybe try researching a bit firther.